# Varnish 3.0.7 suddenly stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, apt, varnish, ubuntu-14.04

Changed one line in default.vcl and after that I couldn't restart. It didn't give me any error or anything. I tried to set it back to the former config but that didn't help.

So I decided to reboot. Start all over. didnt help. And now after several tries to reinstall I'm stuck at this. Nothing happens.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
Unpacking varnish (3.0.7-1~trusty) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libasan0:amd64 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libatomic1:amd64 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libitm1:amd64 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:amd64 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libtsan0:amd64 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up gcc-4.8 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up gcc (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-68.111) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Setting up libvarnishapi1 (3.0.7-1~trusty) ...
Setting up varnish (3.0.7-1~trusty) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an installation of Ruxit Agent that made the Varnish Cache not usable.

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id  Target Id        Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7f08e4b1b740 (LWP 2400) "varnishd" __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
(gdb) bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
#1  0x00007f08e348768d in _L_lock_1082 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007f08e3487607 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x680240) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:134
#3  0x0000000000455b7c in ?? ()
#4  0x000000000045893d in malloc ()
#5  0x00007f08e464a516 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libruxitagentproc.so
#6  0x00007f08e4645197 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libruxitagentproc.so
#7  0x00007f08e4639d05 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libruxitagentproc.so
#8  0x00007f08e46373e1 in open () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu//libruxitagentproc.so
#9  0x0000000000455b97 in ?? ()
#10 0x000000000045893d in malloc ()
#11 0x00007f08e44271a8 in VSB_new () from /usr/lib/varnish/libvarnish.so
#12 0x000000000040bd85 in main ()
```

After removing Ruxit it worked again.

Comment: A bit more detail would be appreciated.

Comment: @kasperd I've updated my answer.